# Agenda Job: now() make the job running multiple times

Tags: node.js, agenda

I am scheduling an Agenda Job as below:

```
await agenda.now("xyz");
```

But the above command makes my job running almost every 1 minute. But when I change it to

```
await agenda.every('5 minutes', "xyz");
```

The above works as expected i.e. it runs the job every 5 minutes.

But I don't want a recurring job. Rather run it once.

Comment: What is the context in which you are calling `.now`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the `concurrency` of the job definition. It was set to `10` because of which several instances of the same job were running in parallel.

Changing the `concurrency` to `1` solved the issue.